# Submit a web form just refreshes the page

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to submit a form but every time I hit the submit button instead of submitting the data it just straight refreshes the page.

I was originally able to get it to work by doing:

```
doc.getElementByTagName("button")(1).Click
```

but it stopped working a couple of weeks ago which makes me think something on the website changed.

I've since tried using a queryselector & also just submitting the form using form.submit but get the same result of not submitting any data & just refreshing the page.

The line of code that submits is:

```
<button data-testid="submit-eligibility" class="rds-primary-button is-white-labeled-btn eligibility-lookup__PartnerButton-sc-13jrfc8-1 dDEqAx">Submit</button>
```

I also can't use selenium because it is on a work computer & I am unable to download or install anything without admin privileges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

This is the website that I've been trying to submit the form:

https://www.partneroptumfitness.com/

I use sendkeys to input the values from excel & that code still works but I can't even get an error saying that this field needs to be filled out before submitting which is what it normally does but doesn't even show that any longer.

I'm trying to submit the second form on the page.

Comment: The problem is not the code, is the website that is not compatible with IE11. This is why when you try to use VBA which opens IE11 and clicks the button it only refreshes the website. It is exactly what happens when you go to the site and manually click it yourself on IE11.

Comment: You could try submitting direct to the processing page

https://www.partneroptumfitness.com/member-info?submit-code=submit&code=123456789

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try to switch to Selenium & see if I can get it working that way.